# Akka wait till all messages are processed in whole ActorSystem

Tags: akka

is there any way to wait till all messages in mailboxes(and stashes) are processed in whole ActorSystem?
I'm trying to develop architecture of integration tests for system based on Akka. And it would be convenient to have method something like actorSystem.awaitAllWorkDone(), in this case arbitrary test would look like:

1. Start whole environment consisting of many actors
2. Send message triggering functionality being tested
3. Call actorSystem.awaitAllWorkDone(). Which waits till all messages are processed, including message sent from step 2 and all inner communication messages which it causes. For example message from step 2 fires 10 other messages sent to other actors, so it should wait for them too.
4. Now the system in "consistent" state and I can verify it's state. Like verify that all required changes were made in db or all required side-effects were made.

Actually, step 3 can be replaced with waiting for message specific for this test which indicates that all inner-communication are completed. But whole point is to have one "await" method for any test case, and not to searching which message for this test case is indicator that all inner-communication are completed. 
Anybody have an idea how to achieve this?